# Average of image masks in OpenCV

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, mean, numpy-ndarray

Currently I have a variable number of `np.ndarray`'s that represent image masks of the same size. The values in the arrays are either 255 or 0. Now I want to be able to get an average of all of these arrays. I currently have the code:

```
mask = np.mean(masks).astype(int)
mask[mask > 169] = 255
```

`masks` is a list of `np.ndarray`'s of the size `(296, 640)`. But I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object does not support item assignment
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are taking the overall mean of the masks over all axis which reduces it into a single scaler value (object type `int64`). You want to take the average over `axis=0` since you have them contained in a list to retain the **Height** and **Width** of the masks into a single average mask.

```
mask1 = np.random.randint(0,255,(296, 640))
mask2 = np.random.randint(0,255,(296, 640))
mask3 = np.random.randint(0,255,(296, 640))

masks = [mask1, mask2, mask3]

mask = np.mean(masks, axis=0).astype(int)
mask[mask > 169] = 255

mask.shape
```

```
(296, 640)
```

Comment: I did this and I got incompatible shapes - In fact looking at this: `mask.shape, masks[0].shape = (2, 296) (296, 640)`, it's different to the `np.randint` you have done above

Comment: What is the shape of the original `masks`? `masks.shape`

Comment: Should be (296, 640)

Comment: I am confused then, you have 296 1D masks, each mask of shape 640?? Can you explain what the masks are?

Comment: Oh, masks is a native python list of np.ndarrays of the shape (296, 640) each. Sorry I didn't clear that up before.

Comment: also, `(296, 640)` is the shape of a single mask or all masks together?

Comment: Of a single mask

Comment: can you check and confirm the output of masks.shape? because the shape `(296, 640)` doesnt make sense for what you are trying to do

Comment: Right, so what is the `masks.shape` in total? (?, 296, 640)?

Comment: masks is a native python list. Doesn't have a property `.shape`? Each mask is a (296, 640) np.ndarray with a value between 0 and 255, except due to thresholding all values are either 0 or 255.

Comment: they vary between 1 and 3, but let's consider most of the time it should be around 3.

Comment: ok so its `[mask1, mask2, mask3]` where each mask is a 2D array? right? Now what is your output shape that you are expecting after the operation ? `296, 640`?

Comment: `Now what is your output shape that you are expecting after the operation ? 296, 640?` is this correct?

Comment: glad to help anytime :)